# What is the right way to close a frame in wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I have created an application that has a ShellFromFBFrame inheriting from wxFrame window.

The App object is defined as follows:

```
bool ShellFromFBApp::OnInit()
{
//(*AppInitialize
bool wxsOK = true;
wxInitAllImageHandlers();
if ( wxsOK )
{
ShellFromFBFrame* Frame = new ShellFromFBFrame(0);
Frame->Show();
}
//*)
return wxsOK;

}

The ShellFromFBFrame is as follows:

ShellFromFBFrame::ShellFromFBFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
//(*Initialize(ShellFromFBFrame)
wxBoxSizer* MainSizer;
wxBoxSizer* mainContentSizer;
wxMenu* createContact;
...


the ShellFromFBFrame opens a new CreateContactFrame:

void ShellFromFBFrame::OnCreateContact(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
CreateContactFrame* createContactFrame = new CreateContactFrame(NULL,wxID_ANY);
createContactFrame->Show(true);
}


The CreateContactFrame is as follows:


CreateContactFrame::CreateContactFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
//ctor
Create(parent, id, wxT("Create Contact"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1100,700), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
// int num;
// num = wxAtoi(row);
//this->rowToFetch = row;
...

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(CreateContactFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(ID_CREATEBTN, CreateContactFrame::CreateContact)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

But when I close the CreateContactFrame window by close button or cancel button. My App crashes and I get the following process terminated error message in build logs:

```
Process terminated with status -1073740940 (0 minute(s), 12 second(s))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a coding issue but rather a build of wxwidgets library. Works fine with MSVC 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a stack overflow (how thematic!) due to an infinite recursion: your `wxEVT_CLOSE` handler calls `Close()` resulting in another `wxEVT_CLOSE` being generated and so on. Simply remove the handler completely if you have nothing to do in it to fix the problem.

Also, when encountering a reproducible crash, the first thing to do is to build your program with debug information, run it under debugger and look at the stack at the moment of the crash -- in 90% cases this will provide you with the answer, and this would definitely have been the case here when you would have seen the endlessly repeating calls to your `OnClose()` in the stack.

Comment: I am able to hide the Window but I am not able to close the window though. Like you said I have removed the EVT_CLOSE event but the destructor is being called infinitely recursively.

Comment: I don't see how can the dtor be possibly invoked more than one unless you do something in it that you're not showing it here. The advice about looking at the stack trace in the debugger still stands.

Comment: The issue was with the way I have build wxwidgets. I have now compiled the project with Visual studio. Now the app works fine. There was a problem with the way of building with mingw compilation.app works fine with vs. Thanks though.